# Unexpected key printing MacBook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

The problem started after I took my late 2013 MBP to an unauthorized service shop (because official services said they do not service it) where I had the battery changed. Also they said that cleaned up my keyboard. When some keys are pressed down it prints together with another additional symbol. The pairs always the same and look like this:

- 4 or 6 gives: 46
- r or y gives: ry
- f or h gives: fh
- v or n gives: vn
- = or ] gives: =]

I've already tried several fixes:

1. Setting the different time of slow keys in universal access
2. Unshaky with different values of delay (maybe it doesn't work for me because of different keys)
3. Adding new keyboard in input sources
4. Pressed in the middle of the keyboard with my thumbs
5. Reset SMC, NVRAM, PVRAM
6. Boot in safe mode

Only once I have succeeded and typing well for several minutes, after set 3000 delay for key 'r' in Unshaky, and turn off slow keys. But after I switch language, this strange effect turns back again, and after I repeat same steps, they now doesn't give result.

Here is the way how keys are printing now:

[image: MacBook double key failure pattern]

Do you know some other methods to fix it, or I need to replace the keyboard?

Comment: I would suspect that it's a fault with the keyboard itself.

Comment: Hard to imagine any other way to fix this than replacing the keyboard.

Comment: I'd take it back & make them fix it.

Comment: Does the behavior continue with an external keyboard? But I agree with the other comments it is likely the keyboard - perhaps the battery may have damaged it? why did you change the battery was it swelling?