# MacBook keyboard printing unexpected keys

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, mojave

I am using a mid-2015 MBP which is running MacOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Whenever I am typing a `"."` (dot) it is printing `"\."` (backslash + dot). Now I have to manually remove this backslash every time. (It can be little frustrating while coding)

All other keys are working perfectly fine.

I checked all the possible keyboard settings and googled almost all possible phrases to find a solution/hint but couldn't find anything helpful.
Tried restarting the system twice.

Faced issue while logging back in as I forgot a backslash is also being printed along with the "dot" and my password contains a dot.

PS - My MBP has crashed a couple of times in last 1-2 days.
I also checked the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395070/unexpected-key-printing-macbook-pro) but it seems to be a different problem hence asking a different question here.

Comment: Try an external keyboard (doesn’t have to be from Apple).  If it works ok, the internal one could be damaged.

Comment: @TomGewecke USB Ports are not working and I do not have a bluetooth keyboard. Anyways I followed the instruction to reset NVRAM from [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and luckily it worked.
Still sometimes I see that weird behaviour.